# How can I copy table db to db in MySqL

Tags: mysql, copy

```
$server_net=mysql_connect("xxx.xxx.170.54","net_db","dbpass") or die("SQL server error..!");
@mysql_select_db("net_db",$server_net) or die("database error..");
#------------------------------------------------------------------
$server_local=mysql_connect("localhost","","") or die("SQL server error.!");
@mysql_select_db("local_db") or die("Database error..");



mysql_query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS net_db.komisyon",$server_net);
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE net_db.komisyon SELECT * FROM local_db.komisyon");
```

How can I copy table from local to net ?? I want to create table on server like local table.
When I run this query give error (Unknown database)

Answer (score 2):

You're sending the `CREATE TABLE` command to your network server, but it doesn't have any connection to the `local_db` database.

You must either export the data from your local database in some manner (probably best to use [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html), although you could also load it into PHP and then `INSERT` into your network database), or else look into MySQL [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replication.html) or [clustering](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-cluster.html) to keep the databases synchronised.